# Scatter Points inside object

Tags: geometry-nodes

The point distribute is supposed to scatter points inside an object, but this has been removed in 3.0, how the hell am I supposed to scatter points inside an object.

Comment: The point distribute node from 2.93 only scattered points on faces, so it has been renamed 'Distribute points on faces'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Randomly add points inside a volume]

You can create get the min and the max of the object so that you can plug it into the random value node that will set the position of each point randomly inside the bounding box.

To check if the point is inside the mesh, you can use the raycast to point into itself, and delete the point that is not inside the mesh

Comment: Very creative solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can offset your geometry inward and scatter points on that inner object, you can also use particles to scatter points inside objects.

Comment: This is an essential feature and should not need workarounds. I feel like they have changed to much that I have no idea anymore how geometry nodes work, and this really frustrates me

Comment: I think these features will come back in future updates, geometry nodes and the way they work is still in its anfancy.